# Multiple ips can make download faster?

Tags: ip, iis-7.5, audio-streaming, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a project in IIS 7.5, auido streamming, network server with 10Gbps, 8 ips, had complaints about the slowness of downloading music, if I split the download to 3 ips xxx1 xxx2 xxx3 can leave faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out **why** things are slow to determine what to do about it.  It's impossible to speculate without knowing what tests you've done to narrow down the problem.

I can tell you though that simply having additional IP addresses will not speed things up.  The only thing this would allow you to do is have clients that download more than 4 files at a time from different hosts.

Comment: Yeah, I just use random ips and now getting some page cash erros, the project have diferent response on each ip(maybe some static values), this crazy, and one guy say the download is faster, but I cant believe on that(internet traffic way ,lucky), because for anothers users is perfect, only checking for more opinions. Thanks.